# Why does ARC conversion add "weak" decorator to "readonly" properties?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm just updating a really old project to ARC (2017 – I know).

I've noticed that for `readonly` property declarations, it's adding a `weak` decorator. Eg:

```
// Before conversion to ARC:
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *defaultName;

// After conversion to ARC:
@property (weak, nonatomic, readonly) NSString *defaultName;
```

Could someone explain why it's doing this?

There are a few SO questions and answers about the meaning of `weak`, `strong` and `copy` when applied to a `readonly` property. An example is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15255099/using-weak-with-readonly-property) which seems to be directly contradicted by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405211/does-objective-c-readonly-property-need-to-specify-retain-or-copy) – I don't really see how it makes sense as they only seem to apply on setting a property and a `readonly` has an explicit getter method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the introduction of ARC, the default memory attribute was `assign`, therefore

```
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *defaultName;
```

was the same as

```
@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) NSString *defaultName;
```

That should explain you why ARC migration uses `weak`.

This changed when ARC was introduced - for object types `strong`/`retain` became the default.

This attribute affects only the setters anyway, therefore for `readonly` properties the attribute can have any value.

Comment: Thanks for answering on something of fairly minimal interest to most readers now! It makes sense that it picks `weak` because there's no other specifier given and this is the default, thanks. So, in the case of `readonly`, the ARC converter could just leave it out the memory attribute, but doesn't. Specifying it is redundant, but not problematic?

Comment: @Benjohn It could not leave out the attribute because that could be wrong (`assign` was the old default, the new default is `strong`). The property could be overwritten somewhere as `readwrite` and then the memory attribute would have to be the same...

Comment: That makes sense. Good answer